# Fixing an upgrade error on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, upgrade

I get the following error doing an upgrade on my Raspberry pi. Any idea how I would go about fixing it?

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.24-11+deb9u4_armhf.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/include/netax25/ax25.h', which is also in package libax25 1.1.2-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev_2.24-11+deb9u4_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is not about programming, but system administration/configuration for a Raspberry Pi. Furthermore, there isn't enough information provided here for anyone to diagnose, much less reproduce, the problem. You might be able to get help on [RaspberryPi.SE], but you'll need to provide a *lot* more information in your question if you decide to ask over there.

Answer (score 1):

According to Debian documentation:

> This happens because somebody made a bonehead packaging error, or a graceless transition of including a file in one package rather than the other. The fix is as follows:

Note down the names of the two packages that are both trying to claim ownership of the same file. In this case, package **libc6-dev** is trying to update a file previously installed by package kdebase.

Do a "--force-overwrite" install of the new package, thus:

**Your solution would be:**

```
  dpkg -i --force-overwrite libc6-dev_2.24-11+deb9u4_armhf.deb
```

**Additional Information:** https://wiki.debian.org/Broken_pipe